# Pass numeric variable to a sql statement in R

Tags: sql, r

I can't pass my variable Q1 in a SQL query in R:
code:

```
Q1=23
sqlStatement <- paste("SELECT long,lat FROM "Interpolation" where var1>",Q1,'"',sep=""))

inter1<-dbGetQuery(con, sqlStatement;)
```

Erreur:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "sqlStatement <- paste("SELECT long,lat FROM "Interpolation"
```

Can someone help me please !

Ps:I tried a lot of suggestions that I found on the forum but nothing works
-[How to use a variable name in a SQL statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182337/how-to-use-a-variable-name-in-a-sql-statement)
-[Pass R variable to a sql statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861915/pass-r-variable-to-a-sql-statement-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
paste("SELECT long,lat FROM 'Interpolation' where var1>",Q1,sep="")
```

or

```
paste("SELECT long,lat FROM Interpolation where var1>",Q1,sep="")
```

Comment: @ George Dontas :Thanks a lot for the help it works, there was also a confused between " and ' -----> sqlStatement <- paste('SELECT long,lat FROM "Interpolation" where var1>',Q1,sep="")

Comment: @♦George Dontas :if they are two conditions Q1 et Q2 , what is the syntax?

Comment: paste("SELECT long,lat FROM Interpolation where var1>",Q1," and var2>",Q2,sep="")