# How to get sqldf to allow arguments from a r function

Tags: r, sqldf

Consider the following minimal example:

```
DB1<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))

out1<- sqldf("SELECT x FROM DB1") 


test <- function (db,column){
  fn$sqldf("SELECT column FROM db") 
}

out2<-test(DB1,x)
```

`out1` is fine but when I want to generalise this as a function then I get the error: `object 'x' not found`.

Removing `fn$` didn't seem to help. I can see that the issue may be that the object `db` is a data frame whereas `x` is a string, although it needs to be an argument within the definition.

Comment: letters inside strings are not arguments. You can `paste()` together a query string, e.g., `db <- "DB1"`, `"col <- x"` and `query <- paste("SELECT", col, "FROM", db)`.

Comment: And I have no idea where you got `fn` from or what you expect it to do here.

Comment: @GregorThomas I believe the `fn$` stuff come from the [gsubfn](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gsubfn) package.

Comment: See also the base function `sprintf` or the `glue` package for potentially more friendly ways of creating query strings.

Comment: @GregorThomas The fn$ came from a comment on another question made by (who I believe to be) the package author https://stackoverflow.com/q/38421343/1154853

Comment: Ah, I see. MrFlick is right, it's from the `gsubfn` package [which is loaded by sqldf](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#example-5-insert-variables).

Answer (score 2):

Use $column in the sql string and pass the column as a character string.  The [...] is in case the column name has a dot in it which is accepted by R but must be escaped to use it in SQL.

(Despite the fact that tidyverse does it it is generally not a good idea to use nonstandard evaluation and using it will make your software harder to write and to use.  That means we should pass "x" instead of x. A key advantage is that then it becomes easy to store the variable name itself in a variable, as opposed to hard coding it, which may be desirable when writing functions which should be general.)

```
library(sqldf)

test2 <- function (db, column) {
  fn$sqldf("SELECT [$column] FROM db") 
}

DB1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
test2(DB1, "x")
##   x
## 1 1
## 2 2
## 3 3
```

If you did want to use NSE anyways, despite my warning, then it would be like this.

```
library(sqldf)

test3 <- function (db, column) {
  column <- deparse(substitute(column))
  fn$sqldf("SELECT [$column] FROM db") 
}

DB1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))
test3(DB1, x)
##   x
## 1 1
## 2 2
## 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function using strings, and paste those strings together to get a correct query:

```
library(sqldf)
DB1<-data.frame(x=c(1,2,3))
out1<- sqldf("SELECT x FROM DB1") 

test <- function (db,column){
  sqldf(paste("SELECT", column, "FROM", db)) 
}

out2<-test("DB1", "x")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match.call` to get the function call. If you remove the first element which is the function, you have a list of quoted arguments which you can convert to character strings with `as.character`. Once you have this list of named character values you can use that as the environment for `glue` and surround the parts you want substituted from this environment with `{}`.

```r
library(sqldf)
#> Loading required package: gsubfn
#> Loading required package: proto
#> Loading required package: RSQLite
#> Warning: package 'RSQLite' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(glue)
#> Warning: package 'glue' was built under R version 4.1.2

DB1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3))

test <- function(db, column) {
  to_sub <- lapply(match.call()[-1], as.character)
  sqldf(glue("SELECT {column} FROM {db} where {column} < 3", .envir = to_sub))
}

test(DB1, x)
#>   x
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1.9000)</sup>